# Could Not Attach Running Process with GDB Debugger

Tags: postgresql, gdb, apache-age

The following error occurred while attempting to use gdb to debug errors in Apache Age. The postgres server was started using `pg_ctl` and a connection to a database was established using `psql`. The running process ID (pid) of psql was found using the `SELECT pg_backend_pid()` command. However, when attempting to attach gdb to the psql process using `gdb --pid 4585`, the following error message was received:

```
Attaching to process 4585
Could not attach to process.  If your uid matches the uid of the target
process, check the setting of /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope, or try
again as the root user.  For more details, see /etc/sysctl.d/10-ptrace.conf
ptrace: Operation not permitted.
```

Afterwards, I attempted to run gdb with elevated privileges by using the command `sudo gdb --pid 4585`. However, the following error message was displayed:

```
Starting program: /home/mohayu/Desktop/age_installation/pg/postgresql-11.18/bin/postgres 
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
"root" execution of the PostgreSQL server is not permitted.
The server must be started under an unprivileged user ID to prevent
possible system security compromise.  See the documentation for
more information on how to properly start the server.
[Inferior 1 (process 5056) exited with code 01]
```

If you are unsure about the reasons behind the errors occurring, just tell me on how to debug Apache Age with gdb.

Comment: Please refer to this [post](https://askubuntu.com/a/41656). You need to disable a restriction that prevents GDB from ptracing a non-child process.

Answer (score 1):

Run `gdb` while you are the user who owns the PostgreSQL processes, usually `postgres`.

Make sure you have the PostgreSQL debugging symbols installed and that the extension is built with `-g` or `-ggdb`.

Answer (score 0):

With your first approach, using `gdb --pid 4585`, I got the same error. Although in the second approach using `sudo` I was successful, I have another suggestion:

First, try just the `sudo gdb` command. The system must return the following:

```
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word".
(gdb)
```

Then, use the `attach [ID]` command replacing `[ID]` with the pid. If it succeeds, the terminal will return something similar to the following messages:

```
Reading symbols from /usr/local/pgsql-12/bin/postgres...
Reading symbols from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0...
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug/.build-id/7b/4536f41cdaa5888408e82d0836e33dcf436466.debug...
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
Reading symbols from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1...
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug/.build-id/ce/016c975d94bc4770ed8c62d45dea6b71405a2c.debug...
Reading symbols from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2...
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug/.build-id/c0/f40155b3f8bf8c494fa800f9ab197ebe20ed6e.debug...
Reading symbols from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6...
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug/.build-id/fe/91b4090ea04c1559ff71dd9290062776618891.debug...
Reading symbols from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6...
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug/.build-id/18/78e6b475720c7c51969e69ab2d276fae6d1dee.debug...
Reading symbols from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2...
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug/.build-id/45/87364908de169dec62ffa538170118c1c3a078.debug...
Reading symbols from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files.so.2...
--Type <RET> for more, q to quit, c to continue without paging--
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still facing the issue (on Linux) they can try picking up the process id using the following command and check if that works for them

`ps auxwww | grep postgres | grep -v grep`

Make sure the extension was compiled with the debugging flags and is also loaded in the session.